# Extract(), xmltype() и разбор XML в oracle

Tags: oracle, xml, xmlparser, plsql, sql

Приветы!)

Прошу помочь разобрать XML. Нужно получить блок:

```
<ns2:Sender>
    <ns2:Code>1</ns2:Code>
    <ns2:Name>Value</ns2:Name>
</ns2:Sender>
```

символы до :Sender неизвестны и имеют разные значения, как получить этот тег?

```
extract(xmltype(blob_field, 0), '//Sender/name')
```

Не работает.

Интересует именно Value. Можно ли потом полученные значения пропустить через LIKE или SUBSTR()?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пробовали?

```
//*:Sender/*:Name
```

Comment: Да, конечно!)
быстрофикс

Comment: Похоже, единственное решение - предварительно убить все нейм спейсы из xml. Либо надо знать нейм спейсы, чтобы использовать их в xpath.
_______
Но можно ещё попробывать так: `//*:Sender/*:Name`.

Comment: Представим, что я знаю все нейм спейсы, как их использовать?
`//ns2:Sender/Name` - не работает.

Comment: Так вам второй надо добавить тоже.

Comment: Спс, бро) Я забыл про маски.)